# Calculating the probability of a set of 4 players with at least one hand with more than D doubles (in double 6 dominoes)

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm new when it comes to statistics, so apologies if my math is wrong or even not relatable.

Assuming each player gets 7 dominoes in a field of 28. Player 1 picks 7, then player 2, and so on...

I suspect, to calculate the probability of a single person receiving "D" doubles in "P" picks is:

$$(\frac{7!}{(7-D)!})(\frac{21!}{(21-P+D)!})(\frac{(28-P)!}{28!})$$

When P = 7 and D = 7, I get the probability of you getting all doubles which is 1 in 1184040. I believe 28C7 is 1184040 so this appears to be right since there's only 1 hand that has all doubles.

My instinct was to find the probability of 21 picks and generate the table below (P = 21)

| "D" Doubles | 1 in # Hands |
| --- | --- |
| 7 | 1184040 |
| 6 | 169148.6 |
| 5 | 56382.86 |
| 4 | 33829.71 |
| 3 | 33829.71 |
| 2 | 56382.86 |
| 1 | 169148.6 |
| 0 | 1184040 |

I find the data a bit suspicious. I find it strange that it is as likely for you to be left with a hand of non-doubles after the three players have picked theirs, as it is to be left with the only set of doubles.

While I think the calculation makes sense, I'm not 100% sure I'm getting the calculation I want. As the title states I'm looking for the probability of at least one player getting D doubles.

Comment: If you do not see or know anything about what earlier (or later) players pick at random, then the distribution of your hand does not depend on your position when picking.  This property is known as "exchangeability".

Comment: But I do not understand your table:  shouldn't the probabilities add up to $1$?

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I'm also very suspicious of the table. with the half expectation that all probabilities would sum to 1 - and you're right it doesn't (which makes me believe I'm not calculating the probability correctly). 

The idea I'm trying to calculate is " if it is known what everyone drew, what would be the probability that at least 1 player drew at least "D" doubles. is that clear? I'm not sure if exchangeability applies.

Comment: The probability of a particular player getting all $7$ doubles is, as you say $\frac1{1184040}$ and of one of the four players doing so is $4$ times this, since if one does then the others do not.  You need to clarify your question as to which you are interested in.  For a particular player the number of doubles has a hypergeometric distribution (with expectation $\frac74=1.75$), while for number held by the player with the most doubles the calculation is much more complicated and could be faster with a simulation (with expectation about  $2.97$).

Comment: Would the same multiplication (x4) apply for the probability of a player getting 5 doubles out of 7 picks instead? Would the same apply for 3 doubles?

Comment: The $\times 4$ works for $4$, $5$, $6$ or $7$ doubles as if one gets that then the others cannot.  But it does not work for $0$, $1$, $2$ or $3$ doubles as then you could have somebody else with at least as many.

Comment: Thanks Henry, do you have any insight on how to handle less than 4?

Comment: The hypergeometric distribution for a particular  player, and simulation for the maximum across the four players.  I have added an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability of a particular player getting all $7$ doubles is $\frac1{1184040}$, as you say, and of one of the four players doing so is $4$ times this, since if one does then the others do not.  You need to clarify your question as to which you are interested in.

For a particular player the number of doubles has a hypergeometric distribution (with expectation $\frac74=1.75$), while for the number held by the player with the most doubles the calculation is much more complicated and could be faster with a simulation (with expectation about  $2.97$).

Here is a simulation, using R:

```
dominoesdoubles <- c(rep(1,7),rep(0,21))

maxdoubles <- function(players, dominoesperplayer){
  max(colSums(matrix(sample(dominoesdoubles,
      players*dominoesperplayer), ncol=players)))
  }

set.seed(2023)

sims4 <- replicate(10^6, maxdoubles(4,7))  # max doubles of 4 players
table(sims4)/10^6
#sims4
#       2        3        4        5        6        7 
#0.218778 0.608484 0.157479 0.014785 0.000471 0.000003

sims1 <- replicate(10^6, maxdoubles(1,7))  # doubles of 1 player
table(sims1)/10^6
#sims1
#       0        1        2        3        4        5        6        7 
#0.097888 0.321116 0.360859 0.176935 0.039354 0.003706 0.000141 0.000001
```

You can see the `sims4` table of simulated probabilities is (allowing for simulation noise) $4\times$ the `sims1` table for $4$, $5$, $6$ or $7$ doubles as you would hope, since if one player gets that then the others cannot.  But it does not work for $0$, $1$, $2$ or $3$ doubles as then you could have somebody else with at least as many.

The theoretical probabilities for a particular player are

```
hyperprob <- dhyper(0:7,7,21,7)
names(hyperprob) <- 0:7
hyperprob
#           0            1            2            3            4            5 
#9.820614e-02 3.208067e-01 3.609076e-01 1.769155e-01 3.931455e-02 3.724536e-03 
#           6            7 
#1.241512e-04 8.445661e-07
```

which is a good match for the `sims1` simulation probabilities after allowing for simulation noise.